# How does react redux's #applyMiddleware ensure the middleware is only applied once by return the #createStore instead of a store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How does the changed signature prevent you from apply middleware more than once? It returns a new #createStore, but this method can be used as a parameter again in another #applyMiddleware just as store can be used again, resulting in duplicate middleware.

> To ensure that you may only apply middleware once, it operates on
>   createStore() rather than on store itself. Instead of (store,
>   middlewares) => store, its signature is (...middlewares) =>
>   (createStore) => createStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat question! I didn't quite see how this was obvious either, but I think it works roughly like this:

1. [`applyMiddleware()`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js) accepts a `createStore()` function as you pointed out. `createStore()` is invoked every time `applyMiddleware()` is called. So, a new store each time these are run.
2. [`createStore()`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js) accepts specifically enhancers, which are things that add onto a store instance. Things like what `applyMiddleware()` would provide.
3. If `createStore()` is given enhancers, it (indirectly) recursively calls `createStore()` without any enhancers beyond that. So enhancers are only applied one time using this.

The only way I see to apply middleware more than once would be to implement your own version of `createStore()`. But you might end up with a circular reference at that point.

Comment: So essentially you're saying that store can be mutated, which means that duplicate enhancers can be added onto to it, whereas createStore will recursively call the vanilla createStore, so that even if you use applyMiddleware multiple times, it will apply enhancers to the vanilla createStore each time, resulting in no duplicates?

Comment: Right, that's basically it. I think in general if you choose to subvert the mechanisms laid out by Redux, then you could break this. But if you stick with them, `createStore()` and `applyMiddelware()` work together to avoid that.